# Connecting two solar panels in parallel with different voltage - circuit model

Tags: solar-cell, solar-energy

I am interested in understanding how two solar panels with different voltages in parallel work. Despite it is not recommended, but it may occur when for example one panel is defected, under shading or near factory producing different hot gases. Is the current computed based on the irradiance only and the voltage hence has a mismatch? or the MPP tracker would be fixed on the minimum MPP of both and adjust the voltage and currents accordingly? From basic circuits, two voltages in parallel can not work but in practice, it does work. So what is the trick in the model which explains the model of PV panels in that conditions?

Comment: They cannot have different voltages when connected in parallel. The trick is output resistance.

Comment: "in practice, it does work" - show us some evidence. If you combine them with diodes the one with the higher voltage will do all the work. If you don't used diodes the higher voltage panel will feed current into the other.

Comment: by it does work, I meant the system is running. I am asking for the explanation using formulas to that or references explaining that. According to you comment, if the higher voltage does all the work, the overall voltage measured will be equal to the higher value? and the current is adjusted accordingly to match the higher voltage?

Comment: Measure the actual voltage you get. Look at the I/V curves for both panels (either published, or measure them yourself at same irradiance) and note the I where that V intersects both curves. In short, one panel won't contribute very much.

Comment: _”System is running”_ Does not conflict with what Andy explained. Please draw a schematic, measure the voltage and current in every node and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Solar panels aren't constant voltage devices, even though they may have a nominal voltage quoted by the manufacturer.

In bright sunlight, the panel with the higher voltage will dominate, and the other will be idle.

In lower light, or if the panels are partially shaded, then the current from each panel will be limited.  Drawing current from them will lower the voltage.  Eventually, the voltage from the higher voltage panel drops to the point that the other panel delivers current too.